# CSS 3 - rounded corners in after and before states

Tags: css

I have a little problem with CSS 3, namely I would create such an object with a single item.
Here's an image of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here's what have I:

**CSS**:

```
body{
background:grey;
    padding:10px;
}
#talkbubble {
margin:0 auto;
box-shadow: 3px 10px 7px #deefe5;
   width: 590px;
   height: 160px;
   background: white;
   position: relative;
   border-radius:10px;
   border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}
#talkbubble:before {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #deefe5;
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   background:white;
   top: 100%;
   width: 228px;
   height: 62px;
   border-bottom-left-radius:         10px;
   border-bottom-right-radius:         10px;

}
#talkbubble:after{
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   top:100%;
   left:228px;
   border-top: 10px solid white;
   border-right: 10px solid transparent;
   background:white;


}​
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="talkbubble"></div>​
```

And a [jsFiddle demo](http://bit.ly/YYrJ5D)

How do I round off the angle between the two parts?

Comment: I am not sure, but this could help you: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

What you've done there has successfully created a box **:after** the DIV element, but if you start to enter text into the DIV it will not "flow" into the bottom section.

To achieve what you're aiming for in CSS3 you would need at least 3 DIVs and transparency effects, and you still would have the problem with text overflowing.

Comment: You could save yourself so much time by creating a .PNG image as a background and using sufficient **padding** to ensure the text fits nicely in the bubble. You'd also have output that works for the ~10% of users still getting by with non-CSS3 browsers like IE 8.

Answer (score 4):

Taken information from [here](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/) you can get this:

```
body
{
    background:grey;
    padding:10px;
}
#talkbubble 
{
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow: 3px 10px 7px #deefe5;
    width: 590px;
    height: 160px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}
#talkbubble:before 
{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #deefe5;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background:white;
    top: 95%;
    width: 228px;
    height: 62px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; 
}
#talkbubble:after
{
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   top:100%;
   left:228px;
   background:-webkit-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 10px, white 10px);
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uCRMQ/2

//Just the background shadow doesn't work.
Now background shadow works for this (at this size).

Lg
warappa

Answer (score 3):

worx like a charm:
http://jsfiddle.net/42DJh/7/

just replace with this:

```
#talkbubble:after{
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   top:100%;
   left:228px;
   border-top: 10px solid white;
   border-right: 10px solid transparent;
   border-top: 10px solid transparent;
   border-left: 10px solid transparent;
   border-top-left-radius:10px;
   background:transparent;
   box-shadow:  -3px -3px 1px white;
}
```

Comment: And Richards A concerns about floating is not an issue, just replace 'height: 160px' into 'min-height: 160px' and everything floats smoothly;